# Running project with the Angular CLI throws an error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

When I build and run the angular 7 application through the angular CLI command it generates this error message:

> The serve command require to be run in an angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found.

Project path definition: `E:\_EXTRA\IMPORTANT\Opps\Project>ng serve -o`

After creating the package installed successfully generating the error message see below.

```
√ Packages installed successfully.
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: I am sure the path you are running the serve command is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded and installed git correctly? https://git-scm.com/download/win
And correctly set your PATH to point at your Git installation?
You may have Git installed on a different drive, or under Program Files (x86). 
check with:

`where git`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have already intalled git.

```
git --version
```

Also I fix this issue by running command below:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=<YouCurrentCliVersion>
```

e.g.

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=8.1.2
```

Sometime it happens because new angular-cli try to use angular.json instead of .angular-cli.json as project file.